# How would you test available directories that a package manager would install?

Tags: bash, shell-script, apt

I'm trying to make some install scripts for a system that has multiple dependencies, and I've figured out how to do `--dry-run` with the package manager (Ubuntu, `apt` in this case) before doing any real installs.

However, after installing the packages, there is need for certain config files to be copied over. How would I check for this to make sure that the destinations are available before committing to the installation?

I don't want to execute the script to have things partially installed and putting the system in an unpredictable state, but if the package involved do not exist, the config directories wouldn't exist either for me to check.

Let's say I want to copy to `base.conf` to `/etc/package/system/`, but `/etc/package/` doesn't even exist. If the destination is misconfigured (e.g. misspelled as `sytem`), it'll error out after package installation during the copy, which may be one of multiple config files that were already copied, so I don't have a way to "roll it back" so to speak. My end goal is to have an install process that does not leave partially copied files behind.

The failure scenario is when multiple files need to be copied. If there are 3 files to copy, and the 3rd file's destination is misconfigured, it'll still copy the first 2 files and error out on the 3rd. The residual files will cause further errors on the next run.

PS: I suspect I might need to go create a real package to deal with the dependencies, but the complexity and time needed is substantially higher and I don't want to invest that right now.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit you post to explain the problem a little further. You say that you managed to perform dry runs. Do you mean that you don't trust the result of the dry run and want to perform further tests before copying the files, or do you simply want to check if the target files already exist before copying, or is there still another requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You can examine the contents of packages ahead of time, without even downloading them; see `apt-file` and its `list` command.

However that will never give you a complete picture, and you can’t build a complete picture of the changes made by an arbitrary package without installing it: packages can ship maintainer scripts which perform additional changes. This means a package can create a directory without that being evident from the package’s metadata, and you can only find it out by analysing the maintainer scripts, taking into account all their side-effects and those of the package’s dependencies.

In your scenario, I suspect that you’ll need a two-phased approach:

- install all the packages you need, using the package-management system;
- check all the expectations you have regarding the resulting directory layout and installed files, and

  - if your expectations are met, copy all your additional files into place;
  - if they aren’t, purge all the packages you installed (with `--autoremove` so that any automatically-installed dependencies are removed too).

Comment: Hmm, this will work actually. I've already created a function to automate the dry-run in one go and installing in one go, so it's just a matter of running through the same array with my cleanup function at the end if it exited with an error code > 0